# How to edit HTML file's content dynamically

Tags: java, dynamic, jsf-2, editor, primefaces

Up until now, when I needed to update the content of any pages, I have always had to update the source code directly and re-deploy the whole application. Right now, I want to implement a feature such that I can update the content of any HTML pages dynamically without having to re-deploy the application.

I tried to implement the feature with PrimeFaces's `<p:editor>` component but it does not work. To be more precise, my functions can correctly update the required page. When I goes to the source code folder, I can actually see my changes. However, subsequent requests for the page still render the old content.

I'd be very grateful if you could show me what I have done wrong. I'd also appreciate it very much if you could show me any other ways to achieve the same goal.

Comment: are you looking for a way to get the full path of the server , so instead of using the hardcoded  Writer writer = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\James\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\MyProject\\MyProject-war\\web\\" + path);
            you want to find a way to get the path of your webapp?

Comment: According to the below answer, I think I need a way to get to the "deploy area". Can you how me how to do it please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code actually was working perfectly. From the above answer of user1068746, I did some research and found this [article](http://www.marceble.com/2009/07/virtual-directories-in-glassfish/). The solution is very simple: creating a virtual directory mapping to my hard-disk's directory. As a result, any updates to my files on the hard-disk will immediately be visible to future requests.

Comment: They will however be lost whenever you redeploy the WAR simply because they are not contained in the original WAR.

Comment: @BalusC When I created the new files, I put in the folder `C:\webContent\` which is outside both the Project folders or Deploy folders. I think that's why after I clean and build, my files are still unaffected.

Comment: This link now appears to be dead.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are editing your work-space from your deployment.    :)

You have 2 places with the code. One is deployed, and the other in your "working space".

First, it sounds to me like you want your working space to be the deployment. This way whenever you are editing something, you will be changing the deployment directly. For that, simply create a new project in your IDE and point it to the deployment folder.

I bet that :

```
C:\\Users\\James\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\MyProject\\MyProject-war\\web\\
```

points to your work-space and not the deployment. so effectively, your deployment is editing your work-space.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this one:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRealPath("/")
```

and if you want the location of the WEB-INF

use the following

```
String fullpath = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRealPath("/")+File.separator+"WEB-INF";
```

and so on...

Comment: I don't think this will work. I need a solid path to a file so that I can read and write that file. The link you suggest is only a link for the browser to request for the page. I cannot write anything to that path.

Comment: try this File aFile = new File(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRealPath("/")+File.separator+"WEB-INF"+File.separator+"someFolder"+File.separator+"someFile.txt");